# How To Change MS SQL 2008 R2 Hostname?

Tags: sql, hostname

I Installed MS SQL 2008 R2 Express And Plesk 11
MS SQL Hostname is ".\MSSQLSERVER2008" Right Now !

I Want Change it to "localhost"

Can U Help Me ?

Answer (score 4):

That's not the host name, it's the instance name.

`".\"` is shorthand for localhost, so you've actually got what you want already. The instance name is what comes after the ".\", in this case `MSSQLSERVER2008`. So what you're asking is to change the instance name, leaving you with `localhost\localhost` which makes no sense.

So to explain further, what you've got there is a connection string with the following format

```
<servername>\<instance name>
```

e.g.:

```
localhost\mssqlserver2008
```

For more information on instance names, take a look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/80767/what-are-named-and-default-instance) question and answer. If you still want to change the instance name, as far as I know there is no reliable method of doing so without re-installing and picking the right name during the installation process, as discussed in [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22002/how-to-change-the-instance-name-of-sql-server-express-2008) question and answer on our sister site for database admins.

Comment: Thanks,But I have Another Windows Server 2003 + MS SQL 2008 That Server Name For Conection String iS : localhost  i want users use localhost for MS SQL Server in connection stroing

Comment: Then change the connection string. As you've been told, ".\" and "localhost\" and "servername\" are the same thing. As is "ip address\" and "FQDN\".

Comment: You're confusing the addressing of the application layer with the underlying identity of the server. For instance, you can call me Joe, or Joseph or Mr. Webster but you're still talking to me by using any of those and I'll respond to any of those methods of addressing me.

Comment: As @joeqwerty says, if you want to change ".\" to "localhost\" then go right ahead.

Comment: i want change "localhost\mssqlserver2008" or ".\mssqlserver2008" to "localhost"

Comment: What you're asking is to rename the SQL instance "MSSQLSERVER2008" to the default instance "MSSQLSERVER".